# Php quiz how to use <select> <option> instead of radio?

Tags: php

I've used [this](http://www.vestedutility.com.au/home_safety_check.php) page to create my own quiz.

I have tried to change the last question to a dropdown selection however the values wont go to the score page?
Any ideas?

```
<td>
    <select>
        <option > SELECT </option>                                   
        <option name="question-10-answers"    id="question-10-answers-A"  value="A" >
            <label for="question-10-answers-A">YES      </label>
        </option> 
        <option name="question-10-answers" id="question-10-answers-B"  value="B">
            <label for="question-10-answers-B" >  NO </label>
        </option>
    </select>
</td>
```

on the score page I've got:

```
 if ($answer10 == "A") { $totalCorrect+=10; }
if ($answer10 == "B") { $totalCorrect+=-10; }
if ($answer10 == "C") { $totalCorrect+=10; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<select>` element itself needs to be given a `name` attribute, for its selected value to be submitted to the server.

The `name` attribute is invalid on `<option>` elements.

`<label>` elements nested inside `<option>` elements is also invalid.

```
<select name="question-10-answers">
    <option value="">SELECT</option>                                   
    <option value="A">YES</option>
    <option value="B">NO</option>
</select>
```